# Have an input field as part of a select list?

Tags: javascript, select, input, embed

I have this code:

```
<select>
  <option>thing one</option>
  <option>thing two</option>
  <option>thing <input type="text"> times</option>
</select>
```

Can a `<select>` input have an `<input>` added inside one of the `<option>`s so the user can fill it out?

Comment: This is not possible with a `<select>` tag but you could roll your own dropdown list using `<DIV>` tags and incorporate an input within storing the selected value in a hidden input.

Comment: i suppose using a `<datalist>` is also not going to do it... *narf*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the editable select list plugin for jQuery

http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/

Comment: not much of a jQuery user...but i'll look into it.  MooTools is more my speed.  but if it gets the job done, what the hell!  :)  thx!

Comment: I'd think you can add some style to it.  I've been using jQuery and plugins for about 6 months and love it.  I have not used this particular plugin, but if it does the job, I'm sure you can make it look good.  Most likely, there is a jQuery plugin for just about anything you want to do.